# Place string before filename in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have the following code:

```
get-childitem *.log | foreach { rename-item $_ $_.Name.Replace("", "backup ") }
```

I want to backup .log files and need to rename them. Let's assume the look like **somefile.log**, I need them to be **backup somefile.log**. Basically I need to insert "backup" followed by one space before the filename. If I try the script above it gives me "String can't have length of 0 (zero)".

Comment: `get-childitem *.log | foreach { rename-item $_ $($_.Name -replace '^', 'backup '); }`

Comment: `Get-ChildItem *.log  | Rename-Item -NewName {'backup ' + $_.Name}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend using .NET String formatting for this purpose, to help you build your new file name. Think of it like a template string, but you're substituting the value on the right-hand side of the `-f` operator for position 0 on the left-hand string.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path *.log | 
    ForEach-Object -Process {
        $NewName = 'backup {0}' -f $PSItem.Name
        Rename-Item -Path $PSItem -NewName $NewName
    }
```

The reason you're getting the exception message is because the `Replace()` method requires that you specify a non-zero-length string as its first parameter. In your example, you're passing in a zero-length string, hence the exception you're receiving.

**IMPORTANT**: The `$PSItem` variable is an alias to `$_`, and is only available on PowerShell v3.0 and later. Use `$PSVersionTable` to check which version of PowerShell you are currently running.

For more information about `$PSItem`, see this document:

```
Get-Help -Name about_Automatic_Variables
```

Comment: Maybe... explain why you use `$PSItem` (and what it is) :-)

Comment: Also don't forget that it doesn't exist pre v3

Comment: Get-Help -Name about_Automatic_Variables